# ngFor and change detection in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the component I update the items with this . let `items: array`

```
  this.api.getItems() // http service call
    .subscribe(
      extras => {
        this.items.push(...extras);
      }
  )
```

Whenever the `http` call is completed the `DOM` will be updated with added items. What I would like to know is if the `DOM` corresponding to the added `items` is updated or The entire `ngFor` is reloaded  ?

Comment: The existing nodes, corresponding to the existing items, stay there. New nodes are added for the new items.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks JB. Do you have any docs or links which could give some more information about this?

Comment: The documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: `*ngFor` didn't properly do this all the time. Just about the time of final release when the animation module became usable, it became more urgent to fix this. Previously some changes could happen all following items to be destroyed and recreated. You can try some animation with items with adding/removing/inserting at random places and you'll see this works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If any of you add it as answer I will accept.